# Is it okay to ask a question on the interpretation of a result or for an alternate solution?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I posted a problem a while back and recently put a bounty on it:

[Locus of centroid, given the slopes of the sides](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842646/locus-of-centroid-given-the-slopes-of-the-sides)

I tried to be as clear as I could about what I was asking (basically just an intuitive understanding of why this formula is so close to the $\tan(A+B+C)$ formula, i.e. has such a simple form in symmetric sums) but I didn't get any extra attention (only some 50 extra views out of which 7 were mine as I kept revisiting it every day). Is it okay to ask for alternate solutions constrained to using a certain approach on MSE (like there, I want a solution using Euclidean geometry and trigonometry, and while I did get some clarity on why the locus is a straight line, I didn't understand why the slope is so simple)? And, is it okay to ask for the interpretation of moreover elementary results like the one in the above question (I'm still an undergrad so I'm pretty sure all the questions I ask are elementary)?

This was originally a test question and I mentioned that in the bounty message but then I was told that my bounty message was unclear and unfortunately, I wasn't able to update/modify my bounty message either. Is that the reason why I did not get attention?

I looked at this link for the interpretation part and it seems that is permitted on the website but I'm not sure about alternate solutions constrained to a particular approach;

[Math.SE's Opinion on Discussing Interpretation of Homework Questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22708/math-ses-opinion-on-discussing-interpretation-of-homework-questions)

Comment: There is an [alternative-proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-proof) tag

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, I will use that right away